# How can I return an object inside a map?

Tags: javascript

How can I return an object inside a map, and inside that map, also return an object...

```
return files.map((file) => {
    const url = file.path === '/index' ? '/' : file.path;

    return {
        url,
        links: ['en', 'nl'].map((lang) => {
            lang,
            url
        },
     };
 });
```

I'm getting a few unexpected tokens with the above closing `}`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You're forgetting a closing parenthesis for the second map.

Comment: Thanks - I tried that and that still gives an unexpected token issue.

Comment: You need to use the `return` keyword in the inner arrow function to return an object. As it is now, `{ lang, url }` is the function body, not the value returned by the function and it is not valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with the arrow function passed as callback to the inner `.map()`; it cannot return an object this way. Also, the closing parenthesis of `.map()` is missing.

The syntax of an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Syntax) says that the curly braces enclose the function body, the same way as they do in a normal function.

In order to return an object you have two options:

1. Use `return` inside the function body:

```js
        links: ['en', 'nl'].map((lang) => {
            return {
                lang,
                url
            };
        }),             // <---- `)` was missing here; it closes `.map(`
```

2. Wrap the returned object into parentheses. This way the first non-space character after the arrow is not `{` and therefore it represents the start of an expression, not the start of a code block:

```js
        links: ['en', 'nl'].map((lang) => ({
            lang,
            url
        })),
```

The second option is also suggested as a solution to this problem in the [documentation of arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Advanced_syntax).

Answer (score 0):

The closing paranthesis for the map was missing. Also, to return an object, you need to enclose the return statement in paranthesis to make sure that the compiler does not confuse it with function body. You can try this:

```
 return files.map((file) => {
    const url = file.path === '/index' ? '/' : file.path;

    return {
        url,
        links: ['en', 'nl'].map((lang) => ({
            lang,
            url
        }))
    }
})
```

Comment: Still errors with unexpected token.